# BCNF and 4NF property

Tags: database, rdbms, database-normalization, bcnf

I read a statement "Relation R in BCNF with at-least one simple candidate key is also in 4NF"

I don't think that it is always true but I am not able to prove it.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: Why do you think you have an opinion one way or the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is true and this is the sketch of the proof taken from the paper  ["Simple Conditions for Guaranteeing Higher Normal Forms in Relational Databases", by C.J.Date and R.Fagin, ACM TODS, Vol.17, No. 3, Sep. 1992](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.130.4170&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

A relation is in 4NF if, for every *nontrivial* multivalued dependency X →→ Y in F+, X is a superkey for R. So, if a relation is in BCNF, but not in 4NF, then there must exists a nontrivial multivalued dependency (MVD) X →→ Y such that X is not the key. We will show that this is in contradiction with the fact that the relation is in BCNF and has a candidate key K constituted by a unique attribute (simple candidate key).

Consider the fact that, in a relation R(T), when we have a nontrivial MVD X →→ Y, (assuming, without loss of generality that X and Y are disjoint), then also the MVD dependency X →→ Z *must* hold in the same relation, with Z = T - X - Y (that is Z are all the other attributes of the relation). We can now prove that *each* candidate key *must* contain at least an attribute of Z and an attribute of Y (so it must contain at least 2 attributes!).

Since we have  X →→ Y and  X →→ Z, and X is not a candidate key, assume that the hypothesis is false, that is that there is a candidate K which *does not* contain a member of Y (and for symmetry, neither a member of Z). But, since K is a key, we have that K → Y, with K and Y disjoint.

Now, there is an inference rule that says that, in general, if V →→ W and U → W, where U and W are disjoint, then V → W.

Applying this rule to our case, since  X →→ Y, and  K → Y, we can say that X → Y. But this is a contradiction, since we have said that R is in BCNF, and X is *not* a candidate key.

In other words, if a relation is not in 4NF, than *each* key *must* have at least 2 attributes.

And given the initial hypothesis, that we have a relation in BCNF with at least a simple candidate key, for the previous lemma, the relation *must* be in 4NF (otherwise every key should be constituted by at least 2 attributes!).